# Ubuntu - connecting 3rd monitor fails with "xrandr: cannot find crtc for output DVI-0"

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, xrandr

I've got a laptop with a DVI and VGA output on the back. With everything connected it will only allow me to run 2 of the 3 monitors e.g. laptop display + VGA or DVI+VGA but not all 3. xrandr says I have 2 CRTC's, 0 and 1. The internet says I should be able to share a CRTC if the modeline is the same, and my 2 external monitors are the exact same make and model. How do I convince the software to drive all this hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the 2 monitor outputs on the laptop were mutually exclusive. It wasn't a software fault after all.

Answer (score 4):

I think this means your driver can't handle the size resolution you want to stretch across those.

Comment: xrandr says I can do 8192 x 8192, My monitors are 1920x1080 + 1920x1080 + 1280x800.

Comment: how do you actually get that information about the maximum resolution that can be supported, from xrandr?